# Selective suppression of output preserving exit code

Tags: shell, error-handling, cron, grep

I have a `foo` program which can either

1. succeed;
2. print `Failure` and fail;
3. or print something else and fail.

I have a short script `foo && bar` run by cron. The case 2 is almost always the case, so my mailbox gets flooded with "Failure" messages from cron.

I want to stop getting "Failure" notifications preserving notifications from successes and from failures with other messages.

I tried to write a bash function `wrap_foo` which behaves like `foo` but doesn't print `Failure`. Something like this:

```
wrap_foo() {
    foo | grep -vF "Failure"
}
wrap_foo && bar
```

But it always fails so `bar` isn't executed if `foo` succeeds.

One way seems to be equality test on `$(foo)` but I'd like to avoid it if possible as output can be lengthy.

Should I use `mktemp` and redirect `foo` output there? If there are no easier ways, how can I save `foo` failure status and restore it after I remove the temp file?

Here is a test suite:

```
foo_failed() {
        echo Failed
        false
}

foo_false() {
        echo Error
        false
}

foo_true() {
        echo Something
        true
}

bar() {
        echo bar
        true
}

wrap_foo()
{
        $1 | grep -vF Failed
}

run() {
        wrap_foo $1 && bar
}

echo should not write anything
run foo_failed
echo should write Error
run foo_false
echo should write Something then bar
run foo_true
```

Here is a solution with a temporary file:

```
wrap_foo()
{
        T=$(mktemp)
        $1 >$T
        X=$?
        grep -vF Failed $T
        rm $T
        return $X
}
```

Can it be shorter?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `bar` in your example?

Comment: `foo` changes files on disk. `bar` performs another action with the same files and must be run only after `foo` succeeded. `bar` output  if any must be sent by mail too. Think of `foo` and `bar` as 2 commands run in sequence with `set -e`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `foo && bar` then?

Comment: Fixed and added tests. `$1 | grep -vF Failed` passes 1 but not 2 and 3.

Comment: passes 1 and 3 but not 2, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

using your test suite, i modified the `wrap_foo()` function to the following, which seems to work:

```
wrap_foo()
{
        foooutput=$($1)
        foostatus="$?"
        echo "$foooutput" | grep -vF Failed
        return "$foostatus"
}
```

output:

```
should not write anything
should write Error
Error
should write Something then bar
Something
bar
```

it's just a tad bit shorter, but there's no tempfile involved.

Comment: There is a downside that long output will take memory.